# Find the highest power of $4$ in $82! + 83!$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'am only getting $4^{13}$ as answer, but the correct answer is $40$.
What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you getting $4^{13}$?

Comment: The maximum power of 2 in 82! and 83! is 26. Hence, the power of 4 is 13.

Comment: Nah, $2^{81}$ shows up. See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=prime+factors+(82!+%2B+83!)

Comment: Why do you think the maximal pow of 2 in 82! is 26?  2|2 and 2|4 and .... 2|82 so the maximal power of 2 must be at least 41.  It's actually quite higher.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We first find the maximum power of $2$ in $82!+83!=82!(1+83)=82!(84)$, since $83$ is odd we want the largest power of $2$ in $84!$.

Using the Legendre-Polignac formula this is:

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\lfloor\frac{84}{2^n}\rfloor=\lfloor\frac{84}{2}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{84}{4}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{84}{8}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{84}{16}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{84}{32}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{84}{64}\rfloor=42+21+10+5+2+1=81$.

So the maximim power of $4$ that divides the number is $4^{40}$

Answer (score 1):

$82! = 82\cdot81\cdot80...2!$

41 numbers between 1 and 81 are divisible by 2.

20 are divisible by 4.

10 are divisible by 8.

$41+20+10+5+2+1 = 79$

$2^{79}$ divides $82!$ i.e. $82! = 2^{79} n$, with n odd.

and $2^{79}$ divides $83!, 83! = 2^{79} (83n)$

$82! + 83! = 2^{79} (84n) = 2^{81}(21n)$

$4^{40}$ is the largest power of $4$ that divides $2^{81}(21n)$

Comment: This method gives a power of $4$ that divides $82!+83!$, not necessarily the maximal power of $4$. From this method, we have $82!=2^{79}m$ and $83!=2^{79}n$ for some odd numbers $m$ and $n$. We know that $m+n$ is even. However, $m+n$ may have some power of $4$.

Comment: $2^{79}|A$ and $2^{79}|B$ so $2^{80}|A+B$?!?!?!?  In this case that is true but why should it be true in general.  And in this case it's not maximul.  $2^{81}|82!+83!$.

Comment: @fleablood It is true in this case, because for both $A$ and $B$, $2^{79}$ is the maximal power of $2$. Thus, $2^{80} | A+B$ is true, but $2^{80}$ is not a maximal power of $2$ as you noted.

Comment: In this case it is true because 79 is maximal in both so factoring out 2^79 from the two terms leaves two odd numbers which must be even.  But the blithe statement 2^79 divides 82! and 2^79 divides 83! so 2^79 divides 81! + 83! is just ... illogical.  2^79|2^79 and 2^79|4*2^79 but that doesn't mean 2^80|(4+1)*2^79.  That's a totally weird statement.

Comment: @fleablood I thought it was obvious that if $2^{79}$ was the maximal power of $2$ in both $82!$ and $83!$ that $\frac{82!}{2^{79}}$ and $\frac{83!}{2^{79}}$ would both be odd numbers.  However, I will admit that I did not rule out the possibility that $\frac{82! + 83!}{2^{79}}$ could be a number that is divisible by $8$ or $(2^{2n+1})$  I have added some clarification to my original post that I hope improves the argument.

Answer (score 1):

$82! + 83! = 82!(1 + 83) = 82!84 = 82!*4*21$.

$\{1,2,3....82\}$ has:  $41$ multiples of 2.  So $2^41|82!$  Of those $20$ are multiples of 4. so $2^{41+20}|82!$.  Of those $10$ are multiples of 8 so $2^{41+20+10}|82!$.   Of those $5$ are multiples of 16 so $2^{41+20+10+5}|82$.  Of those $2$ are multiples of  of 32    and $1$ is a multiple of 64.

So $2^{41+20+10+5+2+1}=2^{79}|82!$ and $2^{81}|(82! + 83!)$.  So $4^{40}|(82! + 83!)$.  So the answer is $40$.